# Using underscore.js in Kanso

Tags: couchdb, underscore.js, couchapp, kanso

Kanso.js is a tool to easily let you build couchapps. As can be read in the documentation it includes the underscore.js module.

But how can I exactly make use of the underscore.js methods in, let's say, a list view? Do I have to require it first? For example I have been playing around a but with the union method:

```
var newArray = oldArray1.union(oldArray2)
```

or

```
var newArray = union(oldArray1, oldArray2)
```

However, Kanso keeps on raising a typeError when requesting the list over HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `require` the `underscore` module at the top of your file. If you're on the `dev` branch of Kanso (version 0.0.8), It looks like this:

```js
_ = require('underscore')._;
```

In Kanso 0.0.7 it will look like this:

```js
_ = require('kanso/underscore')._;
```

Then call `union` from the underscore object

```js
var newArray = _.union(oldArray1, oldArray2);
```

### Edit:

In [Kanso](http://kan.so) 0.2.1 (the current version at the time of writing), underscore has it's own package. Here's how to use it:

1. Add `underscore` as a dependency in your [kanso.json](http://kan.so/docs/kanso.json_format) file.

   ```js
   "dependencies": {
       ...
       "underscore": null
   }
   ```
2. Run `kanso install` in your project directory.
3. Require `underscore` in a module.

   ```js
   _ = require('underscore')._;
   ```

Comment: Hi, @nrw, do you happen to know how this works in more recent Kanso versions? (I don't recall offhand.) Thanks!

Comment: @JasonSmith The require statement should look the same as in 0.0.8, you just need to add `underscore` as a dependency and `kanso install` it. I've edited the answer to be a more useful guide.